# How to deal with different generic classes (sharing a base type) in a collection?

Tags: c#, generics

I have

```
public class BaseClass {
public string Name;
}

public class A<T> : BaseClass {
public T Value;
public Action<T> ToDo;
}

public List<BaseClass> MyList;
```

I fill MyList with

```
A<int>, A<double>, A<SomeUnknownType>.
```

When processing the elements of MyList, I want to call ToDo(Value) without having to know what the specific T is in each case.

Comment: If you need to differentiate between the different subclasses, why are you putting them all in the same list?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Normally, the whole purpose of subclassing is that consuming code doesn't need to be able to distinguish between different implementations.

Comment: @recursive The point (or current use) of subclassing is for *code reuse/sharing* - subtype polymorphism is an unfortunate OO trend, IMOHO :( Interfaces alone are sufficient such that the implementation shouldn't matter.

Comment: How are the items in the list "to be used" later?

Comment: What kind of processing do you need to do with your list?

Comment: To elaborate on my code...

Comment: My derived classes have properties like (how do I get \r to not close this box?)  public class A<T> : BaseClass { public T value; public Action(T t) ToDo; } To process the list, I want to call Action(value).

Comment: @user3281625 Make sure to include such *relevant information* in posts  Update the post, as adding such information in comments is easily lost.

Answer (score 2):

Smells bad, but you can try this:

```
foreach (var item in MyList)
{
    if (item.GetType().IsGenericType)
    {
        Type genericType = item.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        ...
    }
}
```

And you get the generic type into the *genericType* variable.

In order to determine if the type is *A*, you can do this:

```
bool isA = item.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(A<>));
```

Comment: Nice, but how can we determine whether the type is `A` or `B` ?

Comment: Maybe with `item.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(A<>))`

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use `typeof` comparison between the current enumeration result (a.k.a "item") like `if(item.GetType().Equals(typeof(A<>))`

Comment: No, he can't. because `A != A<T>`

Comment: Actually the `T` type does not matter here (so it seems)... but I updated the answer

Comment: it does matter.see the OP's comment.just he didn't provide his full class.by the way that won't work either.`item.GetType().Equals(typeof(A<>)` You should try